# How to set default callback for tooltip title with chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm using `Chart.js` to draw several bar charts. I want to modify the default content of the tooltip of all my chart.

But the following code doesn't work:

```js
Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.callbacks.title = function(tooltipItems, data) {
  return "Overriden title"; // This code is not executed
};

new Chart($("#barchart"), {
  type: 'horizontalBar',
  data: {
    "labels": ["Label"],
    "datasets": [{
      "data": [42]
    }]
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.bundle.js"></script>

<canvas id="barchart" width="80" height="20"></canvas>
```

I know I could pass the callback as an option in each of the Chart constructor, but I would like to set it as a global option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace key `global` with `horizontalBar`

```js
Chart.defaults.horizontalBar.tooltips.callbacks.title = function(tooltipItems, data) {
  return "Overriden title"; // This code is executed
};

new Chart($("#barchart"), {
  type: 'horizontalBar',
  data: {
    "labels": ["Label"],
    "datasets": [{
      "data": [42]
    }]
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.bundle.js"></script>

<canvas id="barchart" width="80" height="20"></canvas>
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this globally, i.e. for all chart types as OP asked?